# Query to find which row has the most joins, simliar to another row

Tags: sql, postgresql

My databases saves users, songs, and playlists, as well as allows user's to save their favorite songs. I want to help user's find playlists that are most similar to their saved songs. Let's say the data looks like this

```
users_saved_songs
user_id         song_id
1                    1
1                    2
1                    3
1                    4

2                    1
2                    3
2                    5
2                    7

3                    2
3                    4
3                    6
3                    8
3                    10

playlists_songs
playlist_id    song_id
1                   1
1                   5
1                   9
1                   13

2                   2
2                   6
2                   10
2                   14

3                   1
3                   2
3                   4
3                   7
3                   10
3                   13
3                   15
```

I want to find playlists that have the most songs in common with a user's saved songs. So given user ID 1, their saved songs are [1,2,3,4]. I want to order playlists, based on how many songs they have in common: playlist 1 has 1 song, playlist 2 has 1, and playlist 3 has 3. What's a query (I'm using Postgres), that would enable me to do this? Bearing in mind that a user may have 100s of saved songs, and there are 10s of 1000s of playlists, that could have anywhere from 1-500 songs in it. Is there anyway to write a performant query to get this info? Or would it be best to cache that "match score" in a separate table (user_id, playlist_id, match_count)?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a `join` and `group by`:

```
select playlist_id, count)(*) as num_songs_in_common
from playlists_songs pl join
     users_saved_songs uss
     on pl.song_id = uss.song_id
where uss.user_id = 1
group by playlist_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of CTEs to get your desired result, the first to compute overlapping songs between each user and each playlist and the second to order those counts descending with `ROW_NUMBER()`, using `playlist_id` to break ties, and then select the first `n` rows for each user (dependent on how many playlists you want to return):

```
WITH user_playlist_songs AS (
  SELECT u.user_id, p.playlist_id, COUNT(p.song_id) aS song_count
  FROM users_saved_songs u
  JOIN playlists_songs p ON p.song_id = u.song_id
  GROUP BY u.user_id, p.playlist_id
),
song_counts AS (
  SELECT user_id, playlist_id, song_count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY song_count DESC, playlist_id) AS rn
  FROM user_playlist_songs
)
SELECT user_id, playlist_id, song_count
FROM song_counts
WHERE rn < 3
```

Output:

```
user_id     playlist_id     song_count
1           3               3
1           1               1
2           1               2
2           3               2
3           2               3
3           3               3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0f52/6)

Note this will give you the playlists with most songs in common for all users. If you only want information for one user, @GordonLinoff answer is the way to go.